# When page loads, how to highlight drop down list only one dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to make one drop down surrounding 1 or 2  PX highlight with other color

I tried with

```
<style>
select:focus {
      background: yellow
    }
</Style>
btn_click{
ddlresult.focus();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Okay? Whats your question? What have you tried? You can't just dump requirements with no effort shown and expect us to write code for you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: What have you tried?  What does your code look like?

Comment: I edited my post with what i tried, My apologizes, for not posted what i tried-David, tnw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give your DropDownList a specific class and then style it with CSS.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="YellowDropDown">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 0" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<style>
    .YellowDropDown {
        border: 2px solid transparent;
    }
    .YellowDropDown:hover, .YellowDropDown:focus {
        border: 2px solid yellow;
    }
</style>
```

Now when you hover or set focus to it, the border will become yellow. The transparent border is there to prevent the 'jumping' of the element when hovered since a border would be added.

Comment: Thank you, I got it